# What is the meaning of "leaving someone on the mercy" here?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms

What's the meaning of the phrase "leaving us on the mercy of God" in the following statement:

> "By associating with any group, we are disconnecting ourselves from [a
> person name] thus leaving us on the Mercy of God."

Answer (score 4):

We can leave someone **TO** the mercy of God, meaning to abandon them to their fate, or a person can **throw themselves ON** the mercy of e.g. a court, God, etc, meaning that they admit some kind of wrongdoing and are willing to submit to any judgement delivered. To be **AT** the mercy of something hostile, e.g. the elements, marauding tigers, is to be helpless against that thing.

Comment: Surely "*at* the mercy of" is used when we abandon them to their fate.

Comment: See edited answer. At the mercy of wolves, dishonest employers, the Gestapo, etc, but not God.

Comment: At Michael Harvey: Good advisory!

Comment: I haven't included leaving or abandoning someone or something to the **tender mercies** of something or someone bad or harmful.